# What should I use to integrate a small database in a website?

Tags: database, php, web

Context: I'm creating a website from scratch, using no plugins aside from jQuery, trying to get comfortable with the basics of how things are done. My website has content that should be managed through a small database ( i think at least ). For you to get an idea, it will have a homepage with news, a portfolio and a submission form for redirecting e-mails to my inbox.

Problem: I've been trying to read about some possibilities for database integration, but it's a vast world, I'm currently trying to learn PHP using phpMyAdmin and WAMP and running a few tests with a simple .php file, but it seems a bit unstable, sometimes queries work, sometimes they don't (maybe i'm still a newbie).

Question: If you had to pick a DBMS for a case like this, what would you go for and why? I'm looking for something simple to set up and access.

Comment: Question includes answer: what database does phpMyAdmin support? Only one, MySQL/MariaDB. Did I miss something? ;)

Comment: Any one of those will do. I have used all and have no real preference.

Comment: "`it seems a bit unstable, sometimes queries work, sometimes they don't `" That's not PHP, that's you ;-) Test them out in PhpMyAdmin. Btw, which IDE do you use to develop PHP? And which database are you currently using & how does your code connect to it & query it?

Comment: @Mawg Yes you're right, i still have to learn a lot from mySQLi. I'm writing php in raw notepad, and testing it with a small database with phpMyAdmin. Supposedly my website will use XMLHttpRequests to populate the website with all the data, though I'm still figuring out the best way to approach all this.

Comment: I prefer PDO to MySqli, but it's your choice. It's not clear if you will be coding browser, server, or both. Simplest, for leaning purposes, is to learn PHP & use that to access your database & generate HTML. that worked for me for over 10 years before I got round to teaching myself (Angular)JS. YMMV

Comment: https://www.grocerycrud.com/ might make things easy - or it might not.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a PHP framework like Laravel or similar.  It takes care of a bunch of under the hood work like security for you.

Mariadb (formerly mysql) is one of the most common databases out there.  Almost everything supports it.